# Unwanted indentation in org + evil

Tags: org-mode, indentation, evil

From an org heading, pressing evil `o` will open a new line that's indented according to the heading (org level + 1 spaces).  Can this behaviour be turned off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize `evil-auto-indent` to `nil`.